# friend challenged me, what is the error in this

Tags: lua

```
local bigDaddy = 'bruh'
if bigDaddy ~= true then
    for i=1, 3 do
        bigDaddy = typeof(bigDaddy) ~= 'string' and 'bruh'..i or 1
    end
end
```

friend gave me as a challenge but I cant seem to get anywhere, any help?

Comment: seems unsportsmanlike to ask for help, especially if you haven't tried it yourself

Answer (score 1):

In Lua `typeof` isn't a predefined function. To get the type of a value, the `type` function should be used instead.